# How run java code in IDEA like pycharm scentific mode(###)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pycharm, ipython

In pycharm, we can use "###" to run  some python code directly.
And in Idea, we can  execute the java code  expression directly, not need to write a class, main method.
How can we do this in idea,like the "###" in pycharm? So that we can write some code and run directly, and then the idea save the variable, and then we can write some java code again(which can use the variable created before). I think the idea debug mode can run code directly, so can we do this not in debug mode?

Solution or Plugin for direct run java code.

Comment: Try Tools, JShell console...

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PyCharm, but I can suggest some alternative ways to run Java code.

### *The Java Playground*

Oracle [recently launched](https://www.oracle.com/apac/news/announcement/ocw-oracle-releases-java-21-2023-09-19/) [*The Java Playground*](https://dev.java/playground/) at the [dev.java](https://dev.java/) web site. On that page you can type in Java code to be executed immediately. For example, type `System.out.println( "Hello world!" )` and press the Run button (triangle icon). Free-of-cost.

### *JShell*

To run something similar on your local machine, try [*JShell*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JShell), a [read–eval–print loop (REPL)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) provided with [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) products. For details, see [JEP 222](https://openjdk.org/jeps/222).

You can obtain a JDK product from any of several vendors. These vendors include Amazon, IBM, Red Hat, SAP, Adoptium of Eclipse Foundation, Oracle, BellSoft, Microsoft, Azul Systems, and more.

### Web site compilers

Several web sites let you type in Java code as part of a class template, and then compile and execute that code on their server. One I like to use is [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com).

### *BlueJ* IDE

[BlueJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueJ) is an IDE designed for students learning Java. It seeks to reduce the ceremony needed to write, run, and debug Java.

### Paving the on-ramp

The Java team at Oracle has recently been making multiple efforts to [“pave the on-ramp”](https://openjdk.org/projects/amber/design-notes/on-ramp) to learning Java. These efforts will make writing and and running a bit of Java code much easier.

- [Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs](https://openjdk.org/jeps/330)
- [Launch Multi-File Source-Code Programs](https://openjdk.org/jeps/458)
- [Implicitly Declared Classes and Instance Main Methods (Second Preview)](https://openjdk.org/jeps/463)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
In idea debug mode, we can see the variable Visual Presentation. In pycharm, by use #%%,we can also do this. But in jshell, like we cannot have this feature?